# Take URL Parameter and apply to Button in UI Component

Tags: magento2

I am trying to pass in a URL parameter and apply it to a button within the `adminhtml` UI component. Below is the XML for the UI component's button. This is already 1 level deep and I need to pass the ID of the job into my controller `Company\Module\Controller\Action\Stop`, so that the job status can be updated. Passing the URL parameter to the UI component is the only roadblock I'm facing.

URL of current page:

`http://project.dev/admin/mymodule/runjob/index/job_id/1/key/XXXXX/`

Need to pass the `job_id` value to the UI compoentent below (`[X]`).

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    [...]
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="stop_job" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">trigger</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Stop Job</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/action/stop/job_id/[X]</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

The button in question.

[image: UI Component Button]

Comment: Did you fix the this issue ? I m facing the same issue :)

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you find a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add button as given below,

```
  <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="string">Gratifi\Company\Block\Adminhtml\Runjob\AddButton</item>
    </item>
```

And write getButtonData() in that block.